# Form Initialize using selenium webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, manual-testing

I use the following code using `eclipse` to initialize a form

```
WebElement e1 = KD.findElement(By.name("name"));
e1.sendKeys("Srajan ");
```

But in the form the first character `'S'` does not get displayed. 
It starts from `'r'` only. Is the issue be in the coding or the website?

Comment: add more then one "S" and check this.

Comment: Please provide the `html` if possible

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the test code and without knowing about the page source, I think it is a character limit issue.
Check if that field has a character limit and trimming the initial **S**

Also, try using `clear()` before sending new ones if not the character limit issue

```
WebElement e1 = KD.findElement(By.name("name"));
e1.clear();
e1.sendKeys("Srajan");
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to solve this by putting a sleep duration before typing, I fixed this in my project like:

```
WebElement e1 = KD.findElement(By.name("name"));
Thread.sleep(1000);
e1.sendKeys("Srajan");
Thread.sleep(500);
```

This should work, you may not need `Thread.sleep(500);`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it happens sometimes , because the element is not loaded yet. You can try to use wait for that element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("name")));
```

You can also try Thread.sleep(500) but its not recommended. And its also a good practice to use clear() method before sending some input.